# lesscss: how to reparse everything from javascript?

Tags: css, parsing, themes, less

My less file is dependent on many variables such as:

```
@fontRegular:       "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular";
```

And classes make use of those variables, as follows:

```
.thisClass {
   font-family: @fontRegular;
}
```

As you can expect, I need to retheme on-the-fly.

The theme itself redefines those variable, as follows):

```
@fontRegular:       "HelveticaNeue";
```

How can I require less to reparse everything (I mean my less file) and how can I change the variables first?

Comment: In what javascript environment? Node? Browser?

Comment: Browser environment (client side) @seven-phases-max

Comment: See [modifyVars](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modifyvars) and [related topics](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bless%5D+modifyVars) here.

Comment: Thank you, modifyVars was exactly what I was looking for, you made my day @seven-phases-max. Create an answer and I accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lazy. Feel free to answer yourself and accept your own :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply invoke less from you javascript (in this case, it's from my controller) as follows:

```
    less.modifyVars(
        $scope.config.fontStyleHelveticaNeue? {
            '@fontRegular':     "HelveticaNeue",
            '@fontUltraLight':  "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight",
            '@fontDemiBold':    "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold"
        }
        : {
            '@fontRegular':     "AvenirNextCondensed-Regular",
            '@fontUltraLight':  "AvenirNextCondensed-UltraLight",
            '@fontDemiBold':    "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold"
        }
    );
```

Where on the example above, all @-prefixed words are my less variables I update (actually, there are two set there).
Less will rebuild all the css automatically.